# runtime error: signed integer overflow: 8 * 268435456 cannot be represented in type 'int' (solution.cpp)

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm solving a leetcode exercise called  [Evaluate Reverse Polish Notation](https://leetcode.com/problems/evaluate-reverse-polish-notation/) Medium Level.
You probably have seen this error elsewhere. I don't understand why v1*v2 would cause a runtime error.  My solution passed 20/22 test cases.  Can someone with knowledge explain?

Error: runtime error: signed integer overflow: 8 * 268435456 cannot be represented in type 'int' (solution.cpp)

st.push(v1*v2); // runtime error

Solution: one of the test cases' values has exceeded 10^9, therefore, I need to store the value of v1 & v1 in a "long long" which can store up to 10^18

```
int evalRPN(vector<string>& tokens) {
    stack<int> st;

    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i++)
    {
        /*define operators()*/
        if(tokens[i] == "+" || tokens[i] == "/" || tokens[i] == "-" || tokens[i] == "*")
        {
            /*pop two values from stack*/
            int v1 = st.top(); // the cause of the runtime error can be spoted here. "int" should be replaced by "long long" since the output value is greater than 10^9
            st.pop();
            int v2 = st.top(); //same comment as above.
            st.pop();

            if(tokens[i] == "+"){
                st.push(v2+v1);
            }
            else if (tokens[i] == "/")
            {
                st.push(v2/v1);
            }
            else if (tokens[i] == "*")
            {
                st.push(v1*v2); // runtime happened here.
            }
            else if (tokens[i] == "-")
            {
                st.push(v2-v1);
            }
            
        }
        else {
        /*define operands()*/
        st.push(atoi(tokens[i].c_str()));
        }
    } 
return st.top();
}
```

Comment: Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551).

Comment: The error message is very clear and detailed. What part of it causes difficulties?

Comment: Deleted Image thanks for the heads up.

Comment: figured out the problem. One of my cases exceeded the max number it can store(10^9). using long long instead of int fixed the issue.

Comment: You need to post your error as **text**, otherwise nobody knows what your problem is.

Comment: Done. I've also added the solution incase if someone else runs into the same silly error.

Comment: @cloudbrain Please post your solution as an answer instead of editing the question.

Comment: @VLL I didn't edit the wrong answer. The code is still as is. The solution is above the code. Though, Im going to add few comments to the code to make it easy to spot the error